# How can i add values to a user's properties and then save it to a database?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to add some xp to the user.

```
 string username = User.Identity.GetUserName();
                    var user = db.Users.First(u => u.UserName == username);

    GameLogic.AddXp(99, user);
```

This is the method for adding and saving xp:

```
public void AddXp(int xp, ApplicationUser user)
        {
            user.Xp += xp;
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
```

But this does not save xp to the database.

Here is my `ApplicationUser` class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {      
        public int Xp { get; set; }
```

Here is my `ApplicationDbContext` class:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
            Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);
        }

        public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

        public DbSet<CurrentMatch> CurrentMatches { get; set; }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Change tracking in your DB context seems to be disabled when `SubmitChanges()` does nothing. Check the value of `this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` in the `ApplicationDbContext` class, is it `true`?

Comment: I don't have this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled in the ApplicationDbContext in my ApplicationDbContext class, can i just add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the user is logged in that means the user entity is already being tracked, so when you call db.Users.First(...); EF creates another tracking instance for the same user which is why you get the exception "*An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker*".

to solve it simply call AsNoTracking() for Users dbSet as below:

```
var user = db.Users.AsNoTracking().First(u => u.UserName == username);
```

then modify th AddXp method as below :

```
public void AddXp(int xp, ApplicationUser user)
{
    user.Xp += xp;
    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach to update the entity.

```
public void AddXp(int xp, ApplicationUser user)
{
     user.Xp += xp;

     // Mark the entity as modified
     db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I tried and then I get this exception: SystemInvalidOperationException{"An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."}